# I can't install numpy and scipy with python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, installation

Can anyone tell me how can i setup a python working environment with numpy and scipy?
I have succesfully downloaded python but i can't install numpy,it gives me an error "unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Enthought Canopy](https://store.enthought.com/downloads/), which is an easy way to get python with lots of useful packages (including numpy and scipy) built in.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to jh314's answer, there is also [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads).

Answer (score 0):

Download the executable installers from Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) repository. Numpy is [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and Scipy is [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy).